# Is it permissible to have exit row with ordinary seat spacing?

Tags: emergency, cabin-design, seats, evacuation

I was recently flying a flight with an exit row seat on the overwing exit.

I was expecting increased seat spacing for this row but to my surprise the seat spacing seemed exactly the same as rows ahead and behind.

Is this permissible? Are there any rules that mandate minimum seat spacing ( inter row) for exit row seats? I imagine in case of an emergency evacuation it would be very slow for passengers to exit via this row.

Comment: Which aircraft type?

Comment: define "ordinary" seat spacing. [different airlines have different spacings](https://www.airlinequality.com/info/seat-pitch-guide/).

Comment: In general, the rules are that the aircraft must be evacuated within 90 seconds, with half the exits blocked, in the dark, with smoke in the cabin, with debris obstructing the aisles. If the manufacturer can demonstrate that without having to sacrifice a row of seats, then they are free to do so.

Comment: If it wasn’t permissible it wouldn’t have passed certification.

Comment: So i am trying to understand the situation. After certification by FAA are airlines allowed to move row spacings? Each airline has different seat spacing by the FAA evacuation trials are only conducted by the aircraft manufacturer for the model right?

Comment: @Federico thanks! By ordinary I meant in comparison to other rows on the same aircraft. I was assuming that the emergency row would need to have larger spacing than other rows.